# Crash using mkt cloud version 7.3.1 - Android - RejectedExecutionException

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

We recently updated our application to use version 7.3.1 of the SDK marketing cloud for Android, we were using 6.4.0 because we still supported API 19 in previous versions of the application.

We saw then that in Firebase Crashlytics users are having a crash related to cloud marketing.

The crash occurs for different versions of Android, such as 8, 9, 10 and 11

The number of threads varies, according to each log, but there are cases where the number of complete tasks is 40, or 1, among others.

Below the information:

Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.salesforce.marketingcloud.cf$1@1f101d3 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@e5e4110 [Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 6]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor $ AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors $ DelegatedExecutorService.execute (Executors.java:630)
at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c.f.a (: 25)
at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c.f $ 2.a (: 24)
at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.f.g.run (: 17)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor $ Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)

Since we are using the latest version available, is anyone experiencing this same problem, or has any solution?

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this crash and can you provide the steps to do so?  We are posturing a fix, but we cannot reproduce this issue locally.

Comment: A fix for this is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Version 8.0.5 has been released and addresses this issue.